# Jenkins: run the job when the project was released( by performing a maven release)

Tags: maven, jenkins, jobs, maven-release-plugin

I have defined a job, and I use Jenkins. I'm pretty new in it. Is it possible to set the job to run each time when the project was released?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "released"? Do you mean maven release build, or just upstream job build completing successfully, or what?

Comment: maven released build. I dont want to call the job each time when a regular build was done. only on release

Comment: How do you know when a build is a release build vs. other type of build?

Comment: Perform Maven release/ Build now

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing a Release vs non-release (daily, commit) build.

1. Check out the functionality of the [Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin)
2. Use two different jobs.  One for "normal" builds, one for Release builds.

For the projects we are running here, we actually use #2 along with the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin).  Normal builds may be promoted to different states (*e.g.* Integration, Verification).  During the promotion, the built version of the code is tagged indicating the promotion. When it comes time to make a release build, only those source versions that have been promoted (and tagged) may be built into a Release.

Comment: what if I will change the release job? can I turn on/off the site generation by some config parameter?

Comment: @dummy What do you mean by "turn on/off site generation"?

Comment: @dummy If you solved the problem, you should write up your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have svn tags I have decided to use svn tags (where all released versions are stored), so I can run my job for a released version.